# Python. Locking the window so that it cannot be minimized

Tags: python

There is such a possibility in Python to lock the app window?

I have one external application window that minimizes itself all the time when another application appears above it.

Comment: yes, ofcourse. `import window; window.lock()`

Comment: I don't mean a GUI application created in python. I need to control an external application.

Comment: oh, you can do that too. `import window; selected_window = window.get('window-name'); selected_window.lock()` in `window-name` put the name of the application, such as chrome or steam or something.

Comment: Okey, thank you, but i have problem 
Exception has occurred: AttributeError
module 'window' has no attribute 'get'

Comment: What can I do, if i have two windows with the same name?

Comment: I don't even know what `window` module you are using, so I'm not sure why you are getting an `AttributeError` rather than an `ImportError`. There is no general answer to this question, other than to use an appropriate module that lets you control or interface with whatever window manager you are using.

Comment: Can you provide more info on what OS you're using as that will probably change what options you have. The `window` module Sahil suggested appears to be the one on PyPi specifically for controlling nurses windows, and it hasn't been updated in 7 years, so its probably not the right option.

Comment: I'm using Windows 10

Comment: @Dzemza I did some digging and didn't find a good option to do this in Python, but basic Google searches for suggestions to lock a window to always be on top came up with ways to do this using either AutoHotKey Scripts or an app called DeskPins. (Note: When I searched for DeskPins, the first result came up as an older version last updated 2015, while the second result was a newer version last updated in 2022)